# Выполнение команды, если в файле логов пинга повторяются строки

Tags: cmd, ping

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане!
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть батник, который пингует хосты и записывает логи пинга в текстовые файлы.
Необходимо доработать его так, чтобы при недоступности узла (хоста) в течение 10 секунд (или через 5 одинаковых строк о неполучениии ответа в логах), выполнялся звук (программа по выполнению звука есть).

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @Vasya1985, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это делается прямо из батника, т.е. проверяется на возращенное число (переменная [errorlevel](http://abaki.narod.ru/i/if.html)) из команды ping.

**Обновление**

Тогда посмотри комманду ping /? Там в параметре должен быть указан аргумент, сколько раз пинговать. По-моему ping -n 10 должен сделать 10 пингов, точно не помню.

Comment: У меня есть эта переменная в батнике, но звук выполняется каждый раз при пинге(неполучении ответа), а нужно, чтобы через несколько подряд  пингов(неполучении ответа) выполнялся. 
Спасибо.